# ImageButton at the right of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add my imagebuttom at the right of the screen like this:

```
Imageview textview                                              ImageButtom
```

The problem is that I tried everything and it didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f5f5f5">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ProfilePic"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:contentDescription="..."
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
...
```

how can I add my ImageButtom at the right of screen? it is for my menu.

thank you friends!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a space which has `weight=1` and `width=0dp` before your ImageButton:

```
<LinearLayout ...>

<TextView .../>    

<Space
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<ImageButton .../>   

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try seting the `layout_weight` attribute of the `TextView` to 1, so that it takes the whole space between the `ImageView` and the `ImageButton` :

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/ProfilePic"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:contentDescription="..."
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center" />

      </LinearLayout>
```

**But**

I strongly suggest you to take a look at [Menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the linear layout on Relative layout, and set android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#f5f5f5">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"><![CDATA[>
    ]]></android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<LinearLayout
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="..."
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ProfilePic"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```